# Tensor notation problem with $C^*$-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis

My question originates from page 2 of the following paper:
http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123684900144

To be short, there $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ are $C^*$-algebras and $L : \cal A\to\cal B$ a linear map. So far so good. Now, a linear map $L_n$ is defined as follows;
$$
L_n = L\otimes 1_n : \cal A\otimes\mathbb C^{n\times n}\to\cal B\otimes\mathbb C^{n\times n}.
$$
And this is what I don't understand. I don't even know what these spaces on the right are. Any hints?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces

Comment: @md2perpe This does not really help cause it doesn't explain what $L\otimes 1_n$ is supposed to be.

Comment: The map $L_n$ is componentwise application of $L$, i.e., $(L(a))_{i,j}=L(a_{i,j})$ for $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

Comment: @Aweygan Ok, so is $\cal A\otimes\mathbb C^{n\times n}\cong \cal A^{n^2}$?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: @Aweygan So, can I regard $L_n$ as a linear map from $\cal A^{n\times n}$ to $\cal B^{n\times n}$ where $L$ is applied componentwise?

Comment: Exactly.  See the second section of [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positive_map).

Comment: @Aweygan Thank you. This is very helpful.

Comment: You asked about the spaces, not about $L \otimes 1_n$.

Comment: Actually, I _did_ ask about $L\otimes 1_n$. But you are right, this included the spaces. So, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $L_n$ is the only linear map from $\mathcal{A}\otimes\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ into $\mathcal{B}\otimes\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ such that, for each $a\in\mathcal A$ and each $M\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$,$$L_n(a\otimes M)=L(a)\otimes M.$$

Comment: Thanks and upvoted.

Comment: @amsmath Thanks.